# Angular, Filter pipe returns empty data/false

Tags: html, angular, pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

i'm trying to follow a custom filter pipe tutorial from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVTNaYBVP88) , but when i run my project on the browser the table become empty. I'm not sure what i have to do to correct this. I already use import `import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';` to app.component.ts and declaration in module.ts .

```js
//filter.pipe.ts

transform(productList: any, term: any): any {
  if (term === undefined) return productList;

  //not sure, but i think it causes by this line
  return productList.filter(function(Product) {
    return Product.prdName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
  })
}
```

```html
<form id="filter">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="filter by name" />
</form>
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList | filter: term">
  <td>{{product.prdName}}</td>
  <!--other table data-->
  <td>
```

When i remove the `| filter: term"` part the table data showed but when i put it back table data show nothing. Can somebody help me figure this out? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Maybe the `term` is null, not undefined, so it pass the first conditional, then your elements inside the `filter` function will be compared with null, consequently your array will be `[]` (empty). To solve this problem compare with `term == null` (so it'll catch null and undefined) instead of `term === undefined`. Also, consider using arrow-function: `return productList.filter(Product => Product.prdName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))`. Also, if I were you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

in your component how is initializated the term variable?

becouse it maybe is not undefined but it is null or empty (''), in the initial condition try comparing with null, undefined and ''.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add a check if the term is null. You could implement your pipe as follows,

```
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], term: any[]): any {
      if (!term) 
        return items;
      return items.filter(item => item.productName.indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PUvODS3t4qBkZePum2lA?p=preview)**